# Conditional sum in the having clause of a grouped query with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

Given two postgres tables `samples` and `sample_values`

```
Table "public.samples"
Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('samples_id_seq'::regclass)
created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
"samples_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
TABLE "sample_values" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_501ff3bcb6" FOREIGN KEY (sample_id) REFERENCES samples(id)
```

and

```
Table "public.sample_values"
Column   |            Type             |                         Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('sample_values_id_seq'::regclass)
value      | integer                     |
sample_id  | integer                     |
created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
"sample_values_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"fk_rails_501ff3bcb6" FOREIGN KEY (sample_id) REFERENCES samples(id)
```

I want to query for instances of `Sample` where all the associated `SampleValue` rows only match a certain criteria.

Using a combination of AR and raw sql the query looks like:

```
ALLOWED_VALUES = [1,2,3]
Sample.joins(:sample_values).
    group('samples.id').
    having('SUM((sample_values.value in (?))::int) = COUNT(*)', ALLOWED_VALUES)
```

I'd like to get rid of the raw sql however, I wasn't able to construct the nodes for the `having` clause with Arel.

I tried `SampleValues.arel_table[:value].in(ALLOWED_VALUES).sum.eq(Arel.star.count)` but that raises the following error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Arel::Table into String
```

Comment: Wouldn't applying condition in where block work in this case? I.e.  `Sample.joins(:sample_values).where(sample_values: { value: ALLOWED_VALUES }).group('samples.id').having(...)`

Comment: I wouldn't be able to find instances of `Sample` which have *only* the values in `ALLOWED_VALUES` that way.